# mPDF nested list styling

Tags: mpdf

I am exporting tablular data to a PDF file, and within one of the cells is/can be a list of items, with each item itself potentially having a child list.

e.g.:

```
<td>  
    <ul>  
        <li>Parent Item text
            <ul> 
                <li>Child Item text</li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
   </ul>  
</td> 
...
```

Styling is minimal.
Parent list:

```
ul.parent-list {
    /*list-style: disc outside;*/
    list-style-type: disc; // just trying verbose styling
    list-style-position: outside;
}
.parent-list > li {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.parent-list > li.first {
    margin-top: 0;
}
ul.child-list {
    /*list-style: circle outside;*/
    list-style-type: circle;
    list-style-position: outside;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

The CSS is fed to mPDF via a separate stylesheet, although I have also tried to resolve this using inline styles.

What I want to appear is typical list styling, with list items padded and the list furniture outside:

[image: what I want]

What I'm getting is this:

[image: what I get]

Is there an issue with nesting lists within mPDF? Their documentation does not mention any issues with lists at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mPDF [doesn't support block level elements within tables](https://mpdf.github.io/tables/tables.html).
Styling must be achieved via inline styles on `span` elements.